# How to reverse the order of rows in my dataframe using Python, But not reverse the index when saving it into another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
[4
 8
 3
 6]
```

into:

```
[6
3
8
4]
```

Python adds the index values 0, 1, 2, 3 to the dataframe, so when I reverse the rows the index values also tag along so the index values of [6,3,8,4] are 4,3,2,1

The problem is when I plot the graph is not ordered in the right way. 
So instead of getting: 
[Yahoo Finance data graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylnjk.png)

I get:

[Python output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA4rg.png)

Answer (score 7):

Seems like reset_index would solve that:

```
df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 8, 3, 6]})

df
Out: 
   A
0  4
1  8
2  3
3  6

df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
Out: 
   A
0  6
1  3
2  8
3  4
```

Comment: How in the Lord's name do you learn to do this stuff ? Where can I learn to manipulate dataframes, pandas, lists etc. ? THANK YOU

Comment: dataframe2 = dataframe.reindex(index=dataframe.index[::-1] works but does not reverse the index, I have to do another line of code as follows: dataframe3 = dataframe2.reset_index(drop=True)